# Printing a non type template inner class

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

I have a non type class template (e.g. Counted) that points to an instance of a class template (e.g. Counter). Everything works fine as long as both template classes are siblings, for example writing a print operator.

Now for several reasons, I want to move Counted inside of Counter as an inner class, and I find myself unable to write a printing operator.

[Here's a working "sibling class" version](http://ideone.com/T77qCh), with the main code here:

```
template < class Count >
struct Counter {
    using count_type = Count;
    count_type instances = 0;
};

template < class Cnt, Cnt& c>
struct Counted {
    using id_type = typename Cnt::count_type;
    id_type id;
    Counted() : id(c.instances) { ++c.instances; }
    ~Counted() { --c.instances; }
};

template < class Cnt, Cnt& c >
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Counted<Cnt,c> sib) {
    os << "printing sibling " << sib.id;
    return os;
}

using SCounter = Counter<std::size_t>;
SCounter sc;
using SCounted = Counted<SCounter, sc>;
```

[Here's the not compiling "inner class" version](http://ideone.com/NxlvpH) with the main code here :

```
template < class Count >
struct Counter {
    using count_type = Count;
    count_type instances = 0;

    template <Counter& c>
    struct Counted {
        using id_type = count_type;
        id_type id;
        Counted() : id(c.instances) { ++c.instances; }
        ~Counted() { --c.instances; }
    };
};

template < class Count, Counter<Count>& c >
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
      typename Counter<Count>::template Counted<c>& sib) {
    os << "printing inner " << sib.id;
    return os;
}

using SCounter = Counter<std::size_t>;
SCounter sc;
using SCounted = SCounter::Counted<sc>;
```

Errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:32:15: error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
  std::cout << j << std::endl;
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Counter<unsigned int>::Counted<(* & sc)>]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
     ^
```

Is there a problem in my code, in my compiler, or is this simply not allowed by the standard ?

Comment: In your `operator<<`, the `Count` in `typename Counter<Count>::` is within a *nondeduced context*. That is, the compiler cannot deduce it from the function argument. You could make the `operator<<` more generic - as in `template<class C> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, C const&)` - and then restrict it e.g. via SFINAE.

Comment: It is easier though to just define `operator<<` as a non-member friend function inside the `Counted` class template.

Comment: Furthermore, [temp.deduct.type]p13 "A template type argument cannot be deduced from the type of a non-type template-argument." So `template<class C, Counter<C>& r, template<Counter<C>&> class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream&, T<r> const&);` is also not allowed, since `C` may not be deduced from `r`.

Comment: Thanks dyp, friending the `operator<<` is exactly what I was looking for. I should have thought about that. Thanks for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Koenig operators are what you want:

```
  template <Counter& c>
    struct Counted {
      using id_type = count_type;
      id_type id;
      Counted() : id(c.instances) { ++c.instances; }
      ~Counted() { --c.instances; }

      friend std::ostream& operator<<(
        std::ostream& os,
        Counted const& sib
      ) {
        os << "printing inner " << sib.id;
        return os;
      }           
    };
};
```

here we create a `friend operator<<`.  It will be found via ADL (or Koenig lookup) when you try to use `<<` with a `Counted` instance.

A different function is created, and no template deduction is done, for each type of `Counted`.

Comment: *"Koenig operators are what you want"* It's an intrusive change/solution, though. Also, you need more `friend` ;)